# Moving texture OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es2

I am trying to implement a sprite of 8 columns and 8 rows in OpenGL ES 2.0
I made appear the first imagen but I cant figure out how to translate the Texture matrix in OpenGL ES 2.0 , the equivalent of the code in OpenGL 1.0 that I am looking is

```
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.2f, 0f);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
```

This are the matrix that I am using atm

```
/**
 * Store the model matrix. This matrix is used to move models from object space (where each model can be thought
 * of being located at the center of the universe) to world space.
 */
private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

/**
 * Store the view matrix. This can be thought of as our camera. This matrix transforms world space to eye space;
 * it positions things relative to our eye.
 */
private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

/** Store the projection matrix. This is used to project the scene onto a 2D viewport. */
private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

/** Allocate storage for the final combined matrix. This will be passed into the shader program. */
private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

/** 
 * Stores a copy of the model matrix specifically for the light position.
 */
private float[] mLightModelMatrix = new float[16];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by OFE in StackOverFlow:

You will need to perform transformations to the texture co-ordinates yourself, you could do this in one of four places:

-Apply the transformation to your raw model data.

-Apply the transformation in the CPU (not recommended unless you have good reason as this is what vertex shaders are for).

-Apply the transformation in the vertex shader (recommended).

-Apply the transformation in the fragment shader.

If you are going to apply a translation to the texture coordinates the most flexible way will be to use your maths library to create a translation matrix and pass the new matrix to your vertex shader as a uniform (the same way you pass the mMVPMatrix and mLightModelMatrix). You can then multiply the translation matrix by the texture coordinate in the vertex shader and output the result as a varying vector.

Vertex Shader:

```
 texture_coordinate_varying = texture_matrix_uniform * texture_coordinate_attribute;
```

Fragment Shader:

```
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture_sampler, texture_coordinate_varying);
```

Please note: Your GLES 1.0 code does not actually perform a translation as you surrounded it with a push and pop.